# Package skype is not available

Tags: apt, skype

I am trying to install skype on ubuntu 14.04 gnome but it gives me "package skype has no installation candidate"

Comment: @Mitch: That other question does not include Canonical Partners among the answers. Should really be added IMNSHO if this is going to be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the Canonical Partners repository.

- Start *Software & Updates* (find it in the Dash)
- Select the *Other Software* tab
- Mark *Canonical Partners*

Comment: Simpler (so better) graphical way :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the source to the source list:

Excerpt from ["Install Skype in Ubuntu 14.04..."](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/to-install-skype-4-0-0-8-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/):

> Open your terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and use the below command to add the PPA. Issue the password for the user when prompted.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"
```

Of course you can substitute `trusty` with *saucy raring quantal precise oneiric natty* if you have respectively Ubuntu 13.10, 13.04, 12.10, 12.04, 11.10, 11.04.

After you can install with

```
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Canonical Partners is not a PPA.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ...but it works even with [http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/](http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/) ;-) I don't know which one is the symbolic link... About _Canonical Partners vs PPA_ right and proper: I suppose the original post came from a time in which `skype` was not yet in the number of the Canonical Partners but still a _lone ranger_ out of the Microsoft realm. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that about the URL, so I removed that remark. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You remove I add it again :-) I don't know if both links will survive in future: it's possible to use http://archive.canonical.com instead of http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu . At present time both are ok, for the future we cannot say.